# How to find multiple paragraph properties by MS Word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that find some properties of the word paragraphs. I need to find '4 Lines or more' paragraphs by using the macro.

I've try this code:

```
If oPar.LineCount = LineCount + 4 Then
```

See below for entire code:

```
Sub CheckKeepLinesTogether()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Const message As String = "Check Keep Lines Together"
Dim oPar As Paragraph
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Dim LineCount As Long

For Each oPar In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
Set oRng = oPar.Range

With oRng
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^13"
        .Execute
    End With

    Set oRng = oPar.Range

        If oPar.KeepTogether = False Then
        If oPar.LineCount = LineCount + 4 Then

            .Select
            Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
            Selection.TypeText Text:=message
            Set oRng = Nothing

        End If
      End If
    End With
 Next
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Please try to learn about range property in msdn. Range is heart of everything for VBA. Please select tag after reading info about the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the faulty line with the uncommented code :

```
    'If oPar.LineCount = LineCount + 4 Then
    If oPar.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines) >= 4 Then
```

By the way, you don't need to set `Set oRng = oPar.Range` twice.

Comment: I don't know why but it's required. Without setting, it just rakes .text as range. That is the ms-word find what fickle.

Comment: Many thanks both Davy C & Rahul. I've test both of your codes and It's work properly. But I've got an error in this line of Rahul's code. 

`Selection.TypeText Text:=message`

Other than that works properly. thanks!

Comment: @Thilina: selection should be replace with the oRng

Answer (score 1):

Not tested

```
Sub CheckKeepLinesTogether()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const message As String = "Check Keep Lines Together"
    Dim oPar As Paragraph
    Dim oRng As Word.Range
    Dim LineCount As Long

    For Each oPar In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    Set oRng = oPar.Range

    With oRng
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "^13"
            .Execute
        End With
            If oPar.KeepTogether = False Then
            If oPar.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines) >= 4 Then
              Set oRng = oPar.Range
                oRng.Comments.Add Range:=oRng
                oRng.TypeText Text:=message
             Set oRng = Nothing
            End If
          End If
        End With
     Next
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     End Sub
```